# Setting SVG objects to specific locations

Tags: python, xml, svg

Is there a way I could move an SVG object to a specific location in Python? I have an floor plan in vectorized format here and let's say for example I would like to place a toilet icon at (222, 382). I couldn't find any suitable libraries to achieve this so any recommendations would be appreciated. Using svgutils I managed to merge the two SVG files the following way

```
fplan = svgutils.transform.fromfile('floorplan.svg')
toilet = svgutils.transform.fromfile('toilet.svg')
fplan.append(toilet)
fplan.save('result.svg')
```

Here's the floor plan

```
<svg width="781" height="480"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M313 181 351 181 351 187 313 187 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M393 166 468 166 468 170 393 170 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M219 324 221 324 221 337 219 337 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M356 341 392 341 392 343 356 343 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M356 243 389 243 389 245 356 245 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M737 44 741 44 741 219 737 219 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 8"/>
<path d="M618 213 741 213 741 219 618 219 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 8"/>
<path d="M382 343 392 343 392 422 382 422 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M289 412 392 412 392 422 289 422 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M618 213 630 213 630 347 618 347 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M382 337 630 337 630 347 382 347 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M36 318 50 318 50 411 36 411 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M36 411 135 411 135 423 36 423 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M37 32 319 32 319 48 37 48 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M37 32 49 32 49 180 37 180 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M618 36 741 36 741 44 618 44 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M289 246 295 246 295 308 289 308 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M217 242 295 242 295 246 217 246 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M385 245 389 245 389 337 385 337 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M618 48 630 48 630 213 618 213 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M313 32 630 32 630 48 313 48 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M217 181 273 181 273 187 217 187 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M217 188 223 188 223 242 217 242 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M37 180 223 180 223 188 37 188 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M313 48 319 48 319 181 313 181 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M127 320 223 320 223 324 127 324 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M127 326 135 326 135 412 127 412 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M36 318 135 318 135 326 36 326 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M289 308 295 308 295 412 289 412 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M217 306 295 306 295 308 217 308 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M217 306 223 306 223 324 217 324 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M273 181 319 181 319 187 273 187 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M127 412 283 412 283 422 127 422 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M283 413 295 413 295 421 283 421 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M217 242 223 242 223 306 217 306 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M37 180 49 180 49 318 37 318 " style="stroke:black" class="wall 2"/>
<path d="M320 151 349 151 349 179 320 179 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 4"/>
<path d="M321 121 349 121 349 151 321 151 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 4"/>
<path d="M189 243 217 243 217 266 189 266 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M356 268 383 268 383 292 356 292 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M276 152 316 152 316 180 276 180 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M356 292 382 292 382 339 356 339 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M189 266 217 266 217 289 189 289 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M189 290 217 290 217 318 189 318 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M56 328 78 328 78 343 56 343 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 4"/>
<path d="M418 135 442 135 442 164 418 164 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 4"/>
<path d="M355 245 383 245 383 268 355 268 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M249 392 274 392 274 412 249 412 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 6"/>
<path d="M223 257 253 257 253 273 223 273 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 5"/>
<path d="M273 49 309 49 309 79 273 79 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M260 309 287 309 287 336 260 336 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 4"/>
<path d="M222 382 239 382 239 411 222 411 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 5"/>
<path d="M411 50 438 50 438 79 411 79 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 4"/>
<path d="M223 310 251 310 251 336 223 336 " style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000 " class="icon 3"/>
<path d="M381 52 410 52 410 78 381 78 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 6"/>
<path d="M253 284 278 284 278 303 253 303 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 6"/>
<path d="M56 379 125 379 125 408 56 408 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 7"/>
<path d="M323 412 365 412 365 422 323 422 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M618 220 630 220 630 316 618 316 " fill="#f0f0ff" stroke="#000000" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" class="icon 1"/>
<path d="M36 367 50 367 50 396 36 396 " fill="#f0f0ff" stroke="#000000" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" class="icon 1"/>
<path d="M37 67 49 67 49 151 37 151 " fill="#f0f0ff" stroke="#000000" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" class="icon 1"/>
<path d="M289 251 295 251 295 288 289 288 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M618 164 630 164 630 203 618 203 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M618 58 630 58 630 160 618 160 " fill="#f0f0ff" stroke="#000000" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" class="icon 1"/>
<path d="M227 181 264 181 264 187 227 187 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M217 191 223 191 223 228 217 228 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M127 329 135 329 135 367 127 367 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M289 342 295 342 295 379 289 379 " style="stroke:black" class="icon 2"/>
<path d="M37 196 49 196 49 282 37 282 " fill="#f0f0ff" stroke="#000000" style="fill-opacity: 1; stroke-width: 1; stroke-opacity: 1;" class="icon 1"/>
```

and here's the toilet icon

```
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 23.92 36.54" width="23.92" height="36.54">
    <defs>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="a2eDjbk0uV"></path>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="e5wOq9mEa8"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58C17.14 26.58 6.78 26.58 3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0Z" id="a9PrqQ5EK"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58C17.14 26.58 6.78 26.58 3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0Z" id="bZhtURMbo"></path>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="b11tFtOzmt"></path>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="c1PUKRgLfD"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 32.89C11.23 32.89 10.63 32.29 10.63 31.56C10.63 30.82 11.23 30.23 11.96 30.23C12.69 30.23 13.29 30.82 13.29 31.56C13.29 32.29 12.69 32.89 11.96 32.89Z" id="g10I3hqSN1"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 32.89C11.23 32.89 10.63 32.29 10.63 31.56C10.63 30.82 11.23 30.23 11.96 30.23C12.69 30.23 13.29 30.82 13.29 31.56C13.29 32.29 12.69 32.89 11.96 32.89Z" id="d89XHCQTO"></path>
        <path d="M3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58" id="a8H8jQsC7x"></path>
        <path d="M3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58" id="f1cQ6pYoi"></path>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#a2eDjbk0uV" opacity="1" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#a2eDjbk0uV" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#e5wOq9mEa8" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#e5wOq9mEa8" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#a9PrqQ5EK" opacity="1" fill="#ffffff" fill-opacity="1"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#a9PrqQ5EK" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#bZhtURMbo" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#bZhtURMbo" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#ffffff" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#b11tFtOzmt" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#b11tFtOzmt" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#c1PUKRgLfD" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#c1PUKRgLfD" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#g10I3hqSN1" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#g10I3hqSN1" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#d89XHCQTO" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#d89XHCQTO" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#a8H8jQsC7x" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#a8H8jQsC7x" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="1" stroke-opacity="0"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
            <g>
                <use xlink:href="#f1cQ6pYoi" opacity="1" fill="#000000" fill-opacity="0"></use>
                <g>
                    <use xlink:href="#f1cQ6pYoi" opacity="1" fill-opacity="0" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="0.6" stroke-opacity="1"></use>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The toilet icon is too verbous. You can delete all you have after the `defs` and transform the `defs` in a `symbol` with a `viewBox` attribute. I'm using `viewBox="-1 -1 26 38"` a little different of what you have since part of the stroke was falling outside the `viewBox`.

Now you can reuse the symbol with `<use>` as many times you need. The use element can take a x and y attributes to be placed where you need. Also since the symbol have a viewBox the use can take a width and a height if you need a different size of the icon.

If you don't need to change the size don't use a a width and a height for the use element

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0781 480" width="781" height="480">
<symbol id="toilet" viewBox="-1 -1 26 38">
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="a2eDjbk0uV"></path>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="e5wOq9mEa8"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58C17.14 26.58 6.78 26.58 3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0Z" id="a9PrqQ5EK"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58C17.14 26.58 6.78 26.58 3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0Z" id="bZhtURMbo"></path>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="b11tFtOzmt"></path>
        <path d="M1.99 36.54C3.99 36.54 19.93 36.54 21.93 36.54C23.03 36.54 23.92 35.65 23.92 34.55C23.92 33.95 23.92 29.17 23.92 28.57C23.92 27.47 23.03 26.58 21.93 26.58C19.93 26.58 3.99 26.58 1.99 26.58C0.89 26.58 0 27.47 0 28.57C0 29.76 0 33.35 0 34.55C0 35.65 0.89 36.54 1.99 36.54Z" id="c1PUKRgLfD"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 32.89C11.23 32.89 10.63 32.29 10.63 31.56C10.63 30.82 11.23 30.23 11.96 30.23C12.69 30.23 13.29 30.82 13.29 31.56C13.29 32.29 12.69 32.89 11.96 32.89Z" id="g10I3hqSN1"></path>
        <path d="M11.96 32.89C11.23 32.89 10.63 32.29 10.63 31.56C10.63 30.82 11.23 30.23 11.96 30.23C12.69 30.23 13.29 30.82 13.29 31.56C13.29 32.29 12.69 32.89 11.96 32.89Z" id="d89XHCQTO"></path>
        <path d="M3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58" id="a8H8jQsC7x"></path>
        <path d="M3.32 26.58C-3.32 12.79 3.32 0 11.96 0C20.6 0 27.24 12.79 20.6 26.58" id="f1cQ6pYoi"></path>
   
</symbol>
  
<use xlink:href="#toilet" x="222" y="382" width="52" height="76"  fill="none" stroke="black"  />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm getting some parsing errors from the xlink, what might be causing this?

Comment: You may find this useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10820351/how-should-i-process-xlink-references-with-lxml-in-python Also: you may try yo use just `href` instead of `xlink:href`

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I could adjust the icon size such that if I have a path as follows `<path d="M85 84 127 84 127 126 85 126 "/>` I could adjust the icon to have the same dimensions?

Comment: You will need to change the viewBox value of the symbol according to the bounding box of the new path. In this case `viewBox="85 84 42 42"`

Comment: Hmm, this seems to remove the object completely. My idea was to change the dimensions of the icon to fit the black rectangle https://jsfiddle.net/L5xz73j4/

Comment: Ask this as a different question.